# Conditional distribution of quadratic forms

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, conditional-probability, multivariate-normal-distribution

Given that $Y$ follows multivariate normal distribution ,i.e, $N_n (0, \sigma^2 I_n)$, we want to find the distribution of $Y'Y$ given that $a'Y=0$ where $a$ is a non zero constant vector.

I know that the distribution of $Y'Y$ would be $\sigma^2 \chi_n^2$ if the condition is not given. How to approach for the given condition?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Shyam. I have added the 'homework' tag, because your Q looks like it is. If it's not, you can edit your Q to remove the tag w/ my apologies. Note that homework gets special treatment here: we provide hints to help you work through the problem, instead of a full solution, so that you can learn from the process (see our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq)).

Comment: Note that $a^{\prime} Y = 0$ part implies that $Y$ is not linearly independent so I don't think that the covariance matrix of $Y$ can be $\sigma^2 I_{n}$. Is it possible that the question has a typo ?

Comment: @mlofton The question asks for a conditional distribution.

Comment: gotcha. my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

This distribution has *spherical symmetry*: that is, any rotation of $Y$ about the origin has the same distribution.  Exploit this by applying a rotation that puts $a$ parallel to the last coordinate.  The condition $a^\prime Y=0$ is tantamount to $Y_n=0.$  Since $Y_n$ is independent of $Y_1, \ldots, Y_{n-1},$ the question asks for the distribution of $Y_1^2 + Y_2^2 + \cdots + Y_{n-1}^2.$  As stated in the question (replacing $n$ by $n-1$), this will be the distribution of $\sigma^2$ times a $\chi^2(n-1)$ variable.

Comment: Thanks whuber but I don't see why $a^\prime Y = 0$ implies that $Y_{n} = 0$. .Could you explain that in more detail ?

Comment: @mlofton In the rotated coordinate system the coordinates for $a$ are $(0,0,\ldots, 0, |a|),$ whence the equation is $$0 = a^\prime Y = 0(Y_1)+0(Y_2)+\cdots+0(Y_{n-1})+|a|Y_n = |a|Y_n.$$

Comment: thanks. I'm pretty bad once I go past three dimensions so I'll think about it some.

Comment: @mlofton Fortunately, this situation can be visualized in just two dimensions.  The two dimensions needed are those spanned by $a$ and the vector $(0,0,\ldots, 1).$

Comment: Unfortunately,  I'm still not following. So, if you don't mind,  going back to your statement, suppose that we just have two dimensions so $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$. Now, it is assumed that  $a_{1} Y_{1} + a_{2} Y_{2} = 0$.  So, are you saying that  $a_{1} Y_{1} + a_{2} Y_{2}$ then has the same distribution as $\sqrt{a_{1}^2 + a_{2}^2} \times Y_{1}$ which has the same distribution as $\sqrt{a_{1}^2 + a_{2}^2} \times Y_{2}$. If so, I believe you but I don't have the intuition for why ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @mlofton It's not intuitive (but it is well known): it's a consequence of two defining properties of the multivariate Normal distribution; namely, that linear combinations of the components also have Normal distributions and that any Normal distribution is determined by its first two moments.

Comment: @Huber: Those concepts are pretty well known by me but I still don't see why the statement is true. Actually, is my statement regarding the square root of $a_1^2 + a_2^2$ multiplied by either one of the $Y_{i}$ having the same distribution as the linear combination $a_{1} Y_{1} + a_{2} Y_{2}$, true ?  Actually, I do get it now. Writing it out helped. The variance of the latter is $a_{1}^2 + a_{2}^2$ with mean zero and the variance and mean of the former is the same. Got it. Thanks so much and my apologies for my denseness.